# If two nested for loops are from range 0 to 10,000, would the big O time be O(1) or O(10,000^2)?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say I have the following function

```
def test(arr):
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(10000):
            print("hello world")

    for num in arr:
        print(num)
```

What would the overall time complexity be? I guess I am more confused about the nested for loops. Would they be considered O(10,000^2) or just O(1) since they are not dependent of the input arr size.

Comment: O(10000^2) is the same as O(1).

Answer (score 1):

The nested loops themselves, as a component of of the whole function, don't scale with the size of the input, and thus run in constant time.

The function as a whole runs in `O(n)` time, as the final for-loop increases in time directly proportional to the size of the input, `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

In typical usage the O notation is asymptotical, that is, it refers to very large x. In this setting, the contribution of the terms that grow "most quickly" will eventually make the other ones irrelevant. So the complexity here is **O(n)**, because of the cycle iterating over the array.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how precise you want to describe your complexity. As we know from books the time complexity showing the number of operations N versus input size n. Based on this statement we could say your algorithm always performs a constant amount of operations for the first loop and the second loop it prints each element so the complexity will be `O(n)`. So I would say only the second loop depends on input therefore the time complexity is `O(n)`